# Condition for a matrix to be a boundary matrix of some simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $p\times q$ matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $A$ to be a boundary matrix $\partial_n$ of some simplicial complex? (see for instance http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~wang.1016/courses/788/Lecs/lec7-qichao.pdf)

To give an example, say we have a 1-simplex $K=\{v_0,v_1,[v_0,v_1]\}$. Then the boundary matrix $\partial_1$ will be $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Clearly, a necessary condition is that $A$ must have only entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$. Also necessary is that each column must have exactly $n+1$ non-zero entries.

However I am having some problem formulating a necessary and sufficient condition(s). It seems quite complicated, there ought to be even some conditions on $p$, $q$. For instance $p$ has to be greater than $q$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $p$ need not be greater than $q$.

Comment: I understand that $p=q$ is also possible. But is $p<q$ possible? Thanks.

Comment: Sure: look at the 3-simplex, for instance, or its 1-skeleton: 4 vertices, 6 edges. (Or look at a simplicial complex with at least 2 vertices and the boundary map from dimension 0 to dimension $-1$, where there is a unique empty simplex. If you like that sort of thing.)

Comment: You should look at a lot of examples to see if you can detect a pattern. If you don't want to do this by hand, SageMath will compute boundary matrices for simplicial complexes.